# How to get access from ToolWindowFactory based class to current source code

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Ian writing a inspection Plugin for IntelliJ. For this Plugin I need access from ToolWindowFactory based class to current source code (cursor position etc.). Theres a way across the PSIManager, but only in AnAction derived classes, not for ToolWindowFactory derived classes. There are any Ideas?

Comment: What exactly is "current source code"? There can be multiple split panes open, each with its own editor.

Comment: hmmm, ok. then the last used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a com.intellij.openapi.editor.event.CaretListener would work? You can register it as follows to receive events for all open editors.

```
com.intellij.openapi.editor.EditorFactory.getInstance().getEventMulticaster().addCaretListener(myCaretListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        CaretListener listener = new CaretAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void caretPositionChanged(CaretEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getNewPosition());
        }
    };
    com.intellij.openapi.editor.EditorFactory.getInstance().getEventMulticaster().addCaretListener(listener);
```